# How to execute an sql query without starting a transaction with PostgreSQL JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I need to execute such query with PostgreSQL JDBC:

```
alter type devel.enum_test add value 'third';
```

So I get `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` saying that `ALTER TYPE... ADD` cannot be executed inside the transaction. So how can I query DB without the transaction in JDBC or tell me any other way do it using java tools?

Comment: Show us the full Java code you're using.

Comment: `Connection.setAutocommit(true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it. For Postgresql jdbc it is

```
 BaseStatement stmt = (BaseStatement)conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeWithFlags(query, QueryExecutor.QUERY_SUPPRESS_BEGIN);
    stmt.close();
```

[https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/core/QueryExecutor.html#QUERY_SUPPRESS_BEGIN]

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it is solving the problem.

Comment: @zloster Sure, but i can do it only tommorrow )